# Static data Redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Does it make sense to mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps when you are only pulling static data from the API and may not modify that data later?

Comment: Could you explain about your goal more detail?

Comment: It does not make sense. You can keep your static data  in a seperate file as const values, export and access from whereever you want.

Or even you can keep your static data in configuration files, if they can change in different environments (test, prod)

Comment: The data is user-specific and is pulled from a database but remains static after it is populated for that user.